# How to conditionally format cell font color depending upon value in Angularjs ui grid when export to excel as CSV

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How to format cell font color when a AMOUNT value is greater than 50 then green else red conditonally when exported to excel as CSV.

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableColumnResizing: true,
            enableFiltering: false,
            enablePagination: true,
            enablePaginationControls: true,
            paginationPageSizes: [50, 100, 250],
            paginationPageSize: 50,
            enableVerticalScrollbar: 1,
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1,
            columnDefs: [
                { name: "RecordID", displayName: "Record ID", cellClass: 'numberAlign', cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, enableColumnMenu: false, width: '10%', enableSorting: true },*/
                { name: "AMOUNT", displayName: "Amount", type: "number", headerTooltip: 'Amount', cellClass: 'numberAlign', cellFilter: 'currency:"$" : 2', width: '10%', enableColumnMenu: false, enableSorting: true, cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><span ng-if="row.entity.SOURCETYPE != \'Distribution of Funds\' && row.entity.AMOUNT < 0" style="color:red;">{{row.entity.AMOUNT | currency}}</span><span ng-if="row.entity.SOURCETYPE != \'Distribution of Funds\' && row.entity.AMOUNT >= 0">{{row.entity.AMOUNT | currency}}</span><span ng-if="row.entity.SOURCETYPE === \'Distribution of Funds\'" style="color:green;">{{row.entity.AMOUNT | currency}}</span></div>' },
                { name: "STATUS", displayName: "Status", cellClass: 'numberAlign', width: '7%', cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, enableColumnMenu: false, enableSorting: false },
            ],
            exporterFieldCallback: function (grid, row, col, value) {
                col.colDef.width = 500
                if (col.name === "AMOUNT") {
                    if (angular.isDefined(value) && value != null) {
                        value = '$' + value.toFixed(2);
                        
                    }
                }
                // Below one is export for branch specific page. wut_details_branch
                return value;
            },
            onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            }
        };
```